# Parsing multiple XML files in the same folder

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse multiple XML files that stored in the same folder. The xml files have the same format. What i want to do is to parse the xml files and copy them into another folder in order to work on them afterwards.

The XML files looks like that :

```
<Racing type="Race">
  <Meeting sport="HH" meetingCode="349083" track="Lol" country="GB">
    <Race result="true" Available="true" raceNumber="13" id="13" revision="1" state="Final Result">
      <Result status="Final Result">
        <Position name="Foo" btnDistance="XX"/>
        <Position name="Ok" btnDistance="1"/>
        <Position name="Done" btnDistance="2"/>
      </Result>
    </Race>
  </Meeting>
</Racing>
```

What i have wrote up to this point is the below code, which just reads a single XML file and show me the RACE element and its attributes.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

xml_file = os.path.join(base_path, "data\\c89b150a-7389-4f2f-a98b-9a241b12616c.xml")

tree = et.parse(xml_file)

root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    for element in child:
        print(element.tag, ":", element.attrib)
```

What i want to do now is to read multiple XML files that stored in the same path and find the ones with **meetingCode="349083"** in order them to copy them in a different path like C:\users\test.

Could you please help ?

After that i second need is to combine the search and for example search and copy the xml file that contains **meetingCode="349083"** and **revision="1"**

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through all xml files in a folder like below

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def process(data):
    xml_obj = ET.fromstring(data)
    for race in xml_obj:
        for k,v in race.items():
            if k == 'meetingCode' and v == '349083':
                return True
    return False

path = '<xml_dir>'
xml_files = os.listdir(path)
for xml_file in files:
    xml_file_path = os.path.join(path, xml_file)
    fp = open(xml_file_path)
    data = myfile.read()
    if process(data):
       #copy the file
```

Comment: Hi @devesh Kumar Singh, thanks for your reply, but your answer just prints the path that the xml files are stored. I want to find the XML file base on the conditions stated on my original post. The xml files are stored on the same folder. All the xml are 4.600 so i want to retrieve and copy only the ones that i need.

Comment: @Panagiotis  If you want only to copy the files that contain 'meetingCode="349083"' why dont you just read each file as a text file (XML parsing is not needed) and check if the require string is in the text or not?

Comment: @balderman, I thought that because i am working with XML files i have to use XML parsing. But i will try it.

Comment: Check my updated answer on processing meetingCode="349083"

Comment: Thanks @DeveshKumarSingh i will check it and let you know for the outcome!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Ok, i run the code with my local paths etc and works fine. I run through all the xml and the def process function works great in order to check the files for the meeting code ! Thanks a lot. Answer accepted! Now i want on the If statement to do the below : IF TRUE --> copy the xml file into another folder i will try with the "from shutil import copyfile

copyfile(src, dst)"

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh on the #copyfile i add the bellow code "shutil.copyfile(xml_file_path,'C:/Users/panos/.spyder-py3/data/new')  " but i get an error <Permission denied: 'C:/Users/panos/.spyder-py3/data/new'> I have add the import shutil. I am not sure why access is denied even though i have access